# Display Product Price WooCommerce with Product Addons Select Box

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Just wondering if anyone can help me here.
Using Woocommerce Product Add-Ons plugin, is there a way to display the product price in the drop down menu? So if I use product add-ons to create a select box option on a product, is there a way to display the product price inside the select box next to the add-on price that is already displayed?

Tried everything but struggling on this. Here's the code to the select.php im trying to edit.

```
    <?php
$loop = 0;
$current_value = isset( $_POST['addon-' . sanitize_title( $addon['field-name'] ) ] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST[ 'addon-' . sanitize_title( $addon['field-name'] ) ] ) : '';
?>
<p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-<?php echo sanitize_title( $addon['field-name'] ); ?>">
    <select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-<?php echo sanitize_title( $addon['field-name'] ); ?>">

        <?php if ( ! isset( $addon['required'] ) ) : ?>
            <option value=""><?php _e('None', 'woocommerce-product-addons'); ?></option>
        <?php else : ?>
            <!--<option value=""><?php _e('Select an option...', 'woocommerce-product-addons'); ?></option>-->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php foreach ( $addon['options'] as $i => $option ) :
            $loop ++;
            $price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_addons_option_price',
                $option['price'] > 0 ? ' + ' . wc_price( get_product_addon_price_for_display( $option['price'] ) ) . '' : '',
                $option,
                $i,
                'select'
            );
            ?>
            <option data-raw-price="<?php echo esc_attr( $option['price'] ); ?>" data-price="<?php echo get_product_addon_price_for_display( $option['price'] ); ?>" value="<?php echo sanitize_title( $option['label'] ) . '-' . $loop; ?>" <?php selected( $current_value, sanitize_title( $option['label'] ) . '-' . $loop ); ?>><?php echo wptexturize( $option['label'] ) . $price ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </select>
</p>
```

So I need to implement this code

```
<?php echo balanceTags($product->get_price_html()); ?>
```

Somewhere in the code posted above.

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain it clearly

Comment: tried to simplify it abit, sorry about the confusing question ahah

Comment: can you share a link?

Comment: websites offline at the moment because its in development so there isnt a link to share:/ simplified the question abit and getting some results, just need to work out where to enter that <?php echo balanceTags($product->get_price_html()); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding in

```
<option data-raw-price="<?php echo esc_attr( $option['price'] ); ?>" data-price="<?php echo get_product_addon_price_for_display( $option['price'] ); ?>" value="<?php echo sanitize_title( $option['label'] ) . '-' . $loop; ?>" <?php selected( $current_value, sanitize_title( $option['label'] ) . '-' . $loop ); ?>><?php echo wptexturize( $option['label'] . ' (' ); echo balanceTags($product->get_price_html()) . $price ?>)</option>
```

To the code replacing the options part.
Does the code look alright? Anything wrong that could go there?